# From html directly to android views

Tags: android, html

I've been searching around and found nothing related to this, but I'd like to know if it is possible to "render" html content in android with automatic conversion of `<div>`s into **frameLayouts**, for example, and `<img>`s into **imageView**. Does anyone know a library to satisfy this criteria?

Comment: Why not just use a `WebView`?

Comment: @Trust I was asssuming this... for the whole application :b

Comment: @Trust considering performance issues

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No. There is no current implementation of this functionality available.